# Где купить windows enterprise?

Tags: windows, лицензирование

Конкретно! На сайте Microsoft понятно...

Но где? в партнёрской программе зарегистрировался, но нигде не могу найти где можно купить oem или enterprise.

Comment: Softline не подойдет?

Comment: Дорого и таких магазинов полно.